# При нажатии на кнопку в блоке меняется текст и через время текст возвращается в исходное положение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста
Внес несколько кнопок на сайт с одинаковыми классами.

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст менялся, а через пару секунд возвращался в исходное положение

Написал следующий скрипт:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bu').click(function() {
    let izm = $(this).text('Скопировано!').fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function() {
      izm.fadeOut();
    }, 600);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user">
  <button class="bu but">Фамилия имя отчество</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
  <button class="bu but">Фамилия имя отчество</button>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку текст меняется, но через 0.6 секунд кнопка исчезает вместе с текстом
Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Потому что `izm` -- это Ваша кнопка, а не текст и Вы скрываете всю кнопку, где предварительно заменили текст, просто сделайте `console.log(izm)`. `fadeOut()` не вернет исходный текст на место, а просто скроет весь элемент. Перед заменой текста, записывайте исходный текст в переменную и потом через временной промежуток меняйте текст обратно используя переменную с исходным текстом.

Comment: да, знаю, что izm - это кнопка.
не совсем понял как console.log(izm) поможет решить проблему. 
и что Вы имели в виду по "через временной промежуток"?

Comment: Вы при нажатии показываете кнопку (`fadeIn`), а через 600мс скрываете (`fadeOut`). Поменяйте методы местами. А чтобы вернуть исходный текст, его нужно или же перед изменением "запомнить" или у кнопок прописать, например, data-атрибут с этим текстом и брать оттуда

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `izm` -- это Ваша кнопка, а не текст и Вы скрываете всю кнопку, где предварительно заменили текст, просто сделайте `console.log(izm)`. Консоль естественно не поможет решить проблему, но поможет понять с чем Вы работаете. `fadeOut()` не вернет исходный текст на место, а просто скроет весь элемент кнопки (возвращаемся к `console.log(izm)`). Перед заменой текста, записывайте исходный текст в переменную и потом через временной промежуток меняйте текст обратно используя переменную с исходным текстом.

> и что Вы имели в виду по "через временной промежуток"

Вы же `setTimeout()` понимаете для чего используете?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bu').click(function() {
    const btn = $(this);
    const btnText = btn.text();
    
    btn.text('Скопировано!');
    setTimeout(() => btn.text(btnText), 600);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user">
  <button class="bu but">Фамилия имя отчество</button>
</div>
<div class="user">
  <button class="bu but">Фамилия имя отчество</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
На примере более понятно стало, что Вы имели в виду.